# Растягивание сайта в ширину

Tags: html, css

Разрабатываю сайт с горизонтальным скроллингом. Возник вопрос: как заставить весь body растягиваться не вертикально, а горизонтально?
Файл html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
<div style="float: left;">
<img src="learning.jpg" width=1000></div>
<div id="newstext">Text</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
$("body").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 60);
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

Файл css

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
 background: #000;
 background-size: cover;
 font-family: SF-UI-Text-Regular, monospace;
 font-size: 16px;
 width: 100%;
}

#newstext{
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.20);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 12px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    padding: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 height: 800px;
 column-width: 250px;
}
```

[image: Вроде все хорошо]
[image: Но когда мы скроллим]

Comment: Может быть вы имели ввиду скроллинг, а не растягивание?

Comment: Нет, скроллинга горизонтального я добился при фиксированном width у body. Задача стоит в том, чтобы body сам задавал свою ширину от своего содержимого.

Comment: Так он и так будет задавать ширину. Главное правильно расположите блоки внутри.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/ например, или https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

В  пропишите следующее:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

В стилях задайте для боди ширину 100%:

```
body{
    width:100%
}
```

Comment: Контенту внутри боди, по логике, придётся задать большую ширину, тогда он сможет скроллиться внутри боди

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex` и `overflow: auto` блоку, например, `<main>`; Если нужно `min-width: XXpx/%` контенту потомков. Таким образом у нас может быть произвольной величины секция контента и флексбокс будет переполняться со скроллом.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.horizontal-section {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.horizontal-section:first-child p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.horizontal-section p {
  min-width: 340px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="horizontal-section">
    <p>بسبب لفرنسا أي أما, يتم هو فهرست واتّجه الأسيوي. أراضي التّحول انه عل, فقد شعار ديسمبر تم, أم معزّزة والديون المبرمة على. الا مع الغالي الرئيسية, فقد سابق والكساد الإكتفاء ٣٠. سنغافورة المتساقطة، شيء بل. تسمّى استدعى الغالي هو جعل, عل هُزم العالم بلا,
  </section>
  <section class="horizontal-section"><p>لفرنسا أي أما, يتم هو فهرست واتّجه الأسيوي. أراضي التّحول انه</section>
  <section class="horizontal-section"><p>اضي التّحول انه عل, فقد شعار ديسمبر تم, أم معزّزة والديون المبرمة عل</section>
  <section class="horizontal-section"><p> تم, أم معزّزة والديون المبرمة على. الا مع الغالي الرئيسية, فقد سابق والكساد الإكتفاء ٣٠. سنغافورة المتساقطة، شيء بل. تسمّى استدعى الغالي هو جعل, عل هُزم العالم بلا,</section>
  <section class="horizontal-section"><p>ل, فقد شعار ديسمبر تم,</section>
  <section class="horizontal-section"><p>, أم معزّزة والديون المبرمة عل</section>
  <section class="horizontal-section"><p>ما, يتم هو فهرست واتّجه الأسيوي. أراضي التّحول </section>
  <section class="horizontal-section"><p>سبب لفرنسا أي أما, يتم هو فهرست واتّجه الأسيوي. أراضي التّحول</section>
</main>
```

Comment: А что если текст будет вылезать из одной секции?

Comment: Не совсем понял, что значит "вылезать", но добавил возможность плавающей ширины для контента.

Comment: у меня текст выводится из базы и может быть произвольной длины, поэтому я использовал отдельный div со свойством column-width и поместил его внутрь section. Когда текст слишком длинный и выходит за пределы section, получается то же самое, что и в самом начале, в самом моем вопросе

Comment: В данный момент в моем примере можно вставлять в первую секцию текст абсолютно любой длины.

Comment: Вы же видели, как работает column-width? Дабы текст не был в одну строку, я использую это свойства. И тогда текст вылезает за пределы min-width данного элемента. Я также пробовал убрать свой div и вставить текст в саму section, дав классу horizontal-scroll то же свойство column-width. Результат тот же